# Can't get jQuery Drag and Drop to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a feature which will ask users a question. There will be 8 possible answers and 2 answer slots. They will drag their choice of answer onto the answer slot and it should accept their choice answer then disable the droppable option so nothing more can be dropped.

The problem I faced was even after dropping a draggable element onto it, the droppable element was still allowing more to be dropped and disabling the droppable feature.

I tried my best to put it into a JSFiddle for you to see but now in here the draggable isn't working either.

Here's what my JQuery looks like:

```
$(init);

function init() {
  $('.answers').draggable({
    containment: '#answerContainer',
    curser: 'move',
    revert: true,
    snap: ".droppable",
    stack: ".answers"
  });

  $('.wrongRest').draggable({
    containment: '#answerContainer',
    curser: 'move',
    revert: true,
    snap: ".droppable",
    stack: ".answers"
  });

  $('#answerSlotOne').droppable({
    accept: "#correctOne, #correctTwo, #wrongOne, #wrongTwo, #wrongThree, #wrongFour, #wrongFive, #wrongSix",
    hoverClass: 'defaultTextHover',
    drop: handleCardDropOne
  });

  $('#answerSlotTwo').droppable({
    accept: "#correctOne, #correctTwo, #wrongOne, #wrongTwo, #wrongThree, #wrongFour, #wrongFive, #wrongSix",
    hoverClass: 'defaultTextHover',
    drop: handleCardDropTwo
  });

  $("#submitForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(cardsDropped != 2){
      alert("You must choose two options here to continue!");
    }
  });
}

function handleCardDropOne(event, ui) {
  var cardValue = ui.draggable.attr('class');
  cardsDropped++;

  ui.draggable('disable');
  $('#answerSlotOne').droppable({
    disabled: "true"
  });
  ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left top'});
  ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);

}

function handleCardDropTwo(event, ui) {
  var cardValue = ui.draggable.attr('id');
  var name = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(name);
  cardsDropped++;

  ui.draggable('disable');
  $('#answerSlotTwo').droppable('disable');
  ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left top'});
  ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
}
```

Here's a link to the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/66frwrz2/

Any help at all would be massively appreciated!

Comment: For starters, in your fiddle you didn't include jQuery or jQuery UI. What errors do you get in your console?

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I've never used JSfiddle before and just had the important in the header of my HTML which I had to remove. But in the console, there's no errors, the two droppable elements just simply won't stop being droppable. No matter what why I try to disable

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your code that is draggable for starters: https://jsfiddle.net/for58mga/2/

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! So basically that's the point I've gotten to and yet no matter what I do to disable the droppable elements once something has been dropped, it won't disable